# Finding the sum of numbers from x to y and the program prints the answer as "x+(x+1)....+y= (sum of # from x to y)"

Tags: python, imperative-programming

For example, the sum of numbers from 1 to 3 would be printed as 1+2+3=6; the program prints the answer along with the numbers being added together. How would one do this? Any help is greatly appreciated as nothing I've tried has worked. I have been trying to use the sum formula to get the answer and a loop to get the numbers being added together... but with no success. Although the hint is to use for loops, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the program. The practice prompt also says that I can't use sum or .join functions :(, I know that would make things so much easier. Omg I'm so sorry for forgetting to mention it.

Comment: Can't we use join?

Comment: @AstikGabani forgot to mention that... nope .join or sum function are not allowed

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: It looks like you have gotten a bunch of good answers already, but posting code that you have tried (even if it doesn't work) shows that you've made a good faith effort. Something to keep in mind for this question if you want to get more answers, and for future questions, but I understand since you're new to stackoverflow. Cheers!

Comment: @DerekO I will definitely keep that in mind the next time I post! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
x = 3
y = 6

for i in range(x, y+1):
    opt_str += str(i) + "+"
    sum += i

print(opt_str[:-1] + "=" + str(sum))
```

Output:

```
3+4+5+6=18
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
def problem1_3(n):
   return n + problem1_3(n-1) if n > 1 else 1
```

or try below

```
n = 0
sum = 10
for num in range(0, n+1, 1):
   sum = sum+num
print("SUM of first ", n, "numbers is: ", sum )
```

output

```
SUM of first  10 numbers is:  55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and list comprehension to assemble the string.

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 3

li = str(n1)+"".join(["+"+str(i) for i in range(n1+1,n2+1)])+"="+str(sum(range(n1,n2+1)))
print (li)
```

Output:

```
1+2+3=6
```

Comment: See OP's comment under the post: "join or sum function are not allowed"

Comment: No I forgot to mention it... it's my fault. I fixed the post now.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to do this is to print a little bit at a time. Use `end=''` in your prints to avoid newlines:

```
num = 3
sum = 0

for i in range(1,num+1):
    sum += i
    if i>1:
        print ("+", end='')
    print(i, end='')
print("=%d" % sum)
```

> `1+2+3=6`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using `for` loops and `print()` function

```
def func(x,y):
    sum = 0

    #Loop for adding
    for i in range(x,y+1):
        sum+=i

    #Loop for printing
    for i in range(x,y+1):
        if i == y:
            print(i,end = '')
        else: print(i," + ",end = '')
    print(" = ",sum)
```

The `end` argument to the `print()` function specifies what your printed string is going to terminate with, instead of the default newline character.

So for your example here,
`func(1,3)` Will output : `1  + 2  + 3 =  6`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
print("Finding the sum of numbers from x to y")
print("Please specify x & y(x<=y):")
x = int(input(" x:"))
y = int(input(" y:"))
numbers = [x]
result = f"Sum: {x}"

for i in range(1,y-x+1):
    numbers.append(x+i)
    result += f"+({x}+{i})"
    
print(f"{result} = {sum(numbers)}")
```

output:

> ```
> Finding the sum of numbers from x to y
> Please specify x & y(x<=y):
>  x:1
>  y:10
> Sum: 1+(1+1)+(1+2)+(1+3)+(1+4)+(1+5)+(1+6)+(1+7)+(1+8)+(1+9) = 55
> ```

output2:

> ```
> Finding the sum of numbers from x to y
> Please specify x & y(x<=y):
>  x:2
>  y:6
> Sum: 2+(2+1)+(2+2)+(2+3)+(2+4) = 20
> ```